# Same cell for different keys in Java SE 8 Hashmap

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, hashmap

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Assume I use "put" function twice:

```
map.put("hello", 4);
map.put("world", 5);
```

I have been taught that there is a hash function behind the scenes which computes the right cell which the value is supposed to enter according to the given key.

My question is:

There is any chance that both computations will lead to the same cell, such that command #2 will result in the same cell given in #1, thus 4 value will be lost?

And if so, how do I make #2 re-map to an other cell if already occupied?
(I don't want to use hash with chaning..)

Comment: What you describe is called a "hash collision". And yes, they can happen easily and are somewhat normal, but `HashMap` takes care of them (in other words, it won't lose any values just because multiple keys happen to produce the same hash value). If it didn't it wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: So, just to make sure - you mean that if a case of "hash collision" happens in this Java implementation, value number 5 will enter an other cell and won't override the previous data. (Open addressing?)

Comment: Actually it's implemented a bit differently (each cell actually holds a linked list and/or tree, depending on some factors) with all key/value pairs that get mapped into this cell. But the outcome is similar: no other data will be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly that

```
map.put("hello", 4);
map.put("hello", 5);
```

However, I think you mean when a hash collision occurs, such that different keys are put in the map, which results in the same hash. This would use chaining.

Because they hash the same, in theory, you could .get(object) for everything before you insert it, and add alter the key if it collided.

But in practice let the map do its job and let the underlying implementation operate how it's designed.